# MaterialDatePicker calendar numbers are not aligned on the center

Tags: android, datepicker, material-ui

**Description:** Numbers are not aligned on the center

[image: Screenshot_1585816072]

**Expected behavior:** Numbers should be aligned on the center

**Source code:** 
**NOTE: The same behavior occured even before adding any style**

```
<style name="OeamtcThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar"
    parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="headerLayout">@style/Oeamtc_MaterialCalendar_Header</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="android:button">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarButton</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarButton</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Oeamtc_MaterialCalendar</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Oeamtc_MaterialCalendar"
    parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="rangeFillColor">@color/oeamtc_accent_transparent_50</item>
    <item name="dayStyle">@style/Oeamtc_CalendarDay</item>
    <item name="dayTodayStyle">@style/Oeamtc_CalendarToday</item>
    <item name="daySelectedStyle">@style/Oeamtc_CalendarSelected</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendarButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
</style>

<style name="Oeamtc_CalendarDay" parent="Test.Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day">
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="itemFillColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearance">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
</style>

<style name="Oeamtc_CalendarSelected" parent="">
    <item name="itemFillColor">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearance">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
</style>

<style name="Oeamtc_CalendarToday" parent="">
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/oeamtc_accent</item>
    <item name="itemFillColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeWidth">3dp</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearance">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
    <item name="itemShapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/Test.ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day</item>
</style>`
```

**Android API version:** 29

**Material Library version:** 1.1.0

**Device:** Oneplus 6t and all nexus emulators

Comment: Use `<style name="OeamtcThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar"
    parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">`

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason this happened. Apparently the main theme of the app has to inherit Material theme.